# how to add an image to my sql server database

Tags: java, sql-server, image

I want to save an image to my sql server database using java. I am using NetBeans IDE, and when I choose picture and click on Save button... my database field(photo) shows `NULL` value.
and these are my codes:

```
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=test";


    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JFrameMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "sa", "oraclee");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JFrameMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

       try {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(" INSERT INTO imageTable (photo) values (?)");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JFrameMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    try {
        ps.setBytes(1, photo);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JFrameMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        ps.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "done..!!");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "sorry, n't saved");
    }
```

Comment: Generally it's not a great idea to store a file (such as an image) in your RDBMS. The better option would be to store the file in a known location, likely a share/directory set aside for storing application related files that have uploaded and then store the (full) file path in your RDBMS. On a separate note, your code strongly implies you're using the `sa` account to access your SQL Server from your applciation. You need to stop that, now. Create a `LOGIN` and `USER` for the application, and grant that `Login`/`USER` only the permission the application needs, and nothing more.

Comment: I beg your pardon @Larnu what do you mean by RDBMS? and about share/directory section: I cant generate the codes? :(

Comment: SQL Server is an RDBMS (Relational Database Management System). You really should know what the technology you're working with is. :)

Comment: I'm afraid, as well, I have no idea what you mean by *"and about share/directory section: I cant generate the codes"*. Do you mean you don't know how?

Comment: yes, I don't know how... @Larnu

Comment: This is an illogical series of `try` / `catch` statements, given if any command in the sequence fails, the ones after it will also fail. Better to put them all within a single try / catch statement. Then if any one part fails, the code will not try the rest that are certain to fail. BTW - what is reported in the logs?

Comment: No error appears during program execution … my only problem is with database image field (photo field) dosent save any value, only NULL value appears @AndrewThompson

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done..!!!

the error were in Save button codes
and these are the final codes:

```
  String name = jTextField1.getText();
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(testJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=test", "sa", "oraclee");
        String url = "INSERT INTO imageTable (name,photo) VALUES (?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(url);
        ps.setString(1, name);
        ps.setBytes(2, personImage);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "saved");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "n't saved");
    }
```

but, first we should add this line in the beginning of the program, to define **personImage** :

```
public class testJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

byte[] personImage = null;
```